# get IP address and email id when receiver open the email

Tags: php

I am using php `mail()` function. but i want that when receiver open email, his/her IP address and email id will save in my db table.

my mail function codes are-

```
<?php
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// ---------- adjust these lines ---------------------------------------
$mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com"; // your GMail user name
$mail->Password = ""; 
$mail->AddAddress("$userid"); // recipients email
$mail->FromName = "Nikhil Garg"; // readable name

$mail->Subject = "Newletter Subscription";
$mail->Body    = "$usermsg"; 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
$mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';  
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->From = $mail->Username;
if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
 ?>
```

They are working well. but i don't understand how to get receiver IP address and email Id when they open this email.

Actually i have more then 5000 email list and i want to sort them by city, state, country. with ip address, i can do that. if you know any other way please suggest

my goal is simple and genuine. I just want to know their country so that i will send emails according their country occasions for better selling results. for sending emails to more then 5000 users and ask them for details is not right way.

Comment: This won't be that easy and I am not even sure if it is that legal. You cannot directly receive the ip adress, after opening the mail. You can work around, if you send an html mail, where you include some functions/urls to call to your server and send the data.

Comment: As a user, I don't want you to get my IP address when I open an email from you.

Comment: Actually i have more then 5000 email list and i want to sort them by city, state, country. with ip address, i can do that. if you know any other way please suggest

Comment: Not possible without javascript hacks (blocked by most email providers) or links to a resource under your control. Even then, *I* would never click such a link.

Comment: I generally don't see HTML mails correctly for this reason (well, my email will render it with all images removed, and ask me if I trust the sender. Most times I don't even need to render it properly). Make sure you send in multipart, therefore, with a text attachment.

Comment: This is basically the wet dream of spammers, hackers and generally nefarious folk. This one falls under the category of "If you don't know how to do it, you can't do it". It's not safe, will use exploits and generally be a case of "No, no, f******* no!" in the eyes of anyone writing a email client, web based email or pretty much anything.

Comment: Why don't you simply ask those 5000 users where they are? If they're willing to give you that info, you can have it. If they're not willing, well then maybe you shouldn't try to get it.

Comment: I know that this is not as accurate, but I suggest you for legal and privacy concerns to use the top level domain for country distinction. E.g. myname@domain.de = Germany. This is legal without any doubt. But not as accurate of course.

Comment: my goal is simple and genuine. I just want to know their country so that i will send emails according their country occasions for better selling results. @Spudley for sending emails to more then 5000 users and ask them for details is not right way.

Comment: This is what mailchimp does .

Comment: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/about-open-tracking

Answer (score 6):

1. Make the email HTML formatted
2. Include a reference to an image on your server in it
3. Add a unique identifier to the query string for that image
4. Have your server record the time, query string id, and request source ip for requests to it

Note that:

- You must familiarise yourself with the relevant privacy laws that you'll be interacting with by doing this (noting that you'll almost certainly be operating internationally)
- This won't work if the user doesn't load the images in the email (and most email clients don't load images by default so that this sort of tracking won't be successful)
- Adding this sort of tracking id will weight your email towards SPAM in some spam filters
- Some of your customers will be upset/offended by you doing this
- You will get the same id from multiple people if someone forwards the email

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called a web beacon, you can use it as far as you give a link back to your privacy policy and in your privacy policy you have to specify about it.

**How it works**
Basically, a 1x1 image is placed in the email, which is requested from your server where you can get the ip address..

**Drawback**
Many mail clients do not load images automatically, so it can't give you accurate stats

**code*

in your mail place an image:
`<img src="http://example.com/file.php" />`

In file.php:

```
//get ip address

//43byte 1x1 transparent pixel gif 
echo base64_decode("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==");
```

Comment: So you are saying to grab the image content from a php file. So every time he opens the e-mail the code will be executed <img src="" ?? This could work. I wonder if mailchimp works that way

Comment: yes this works indeed and you provided the correct answer. "When campaigns are sent through MailChimp, we embed a tiny invisible graphic in the bottom of your HTML email. This open tracker graphic, or web beacon, is unique to each campaign you send. Each time someone opens your email and views the images within it, that open-tracker graphic is downloaded from our server. Each time that graphic is downloaded ..." http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/about-open-tracking

Comment: web beacon is one technique. How can I search for other web programming techniques?

Comment: @themis as far as I know, only possible ways are: 1)web beacon 2)on link click 3)track an image on request, similar to web beacon; as javascript is rejected my mail clients, or if more, I don't know about it, I'm still a beginner..

Answer (score 2):

I have done this, and it works! the problem is that gmail loads the info from their own servers, so, every time a user opens the email,  the recorded IP comes from Gmail servers, so it shows a Google IP address instead of the recipient IP, so it can be done with link tracking, as the recipient clicks the link and it opens a new tab, so you can capture the correct IP

Answer (score 0):

You can't with normal mail.

You send the message (text) away, and have NO control over what the user does afterwards. Now I have NO idea what a `mail id` is, but there are several tricks to get the user's IP, tough I agree with above users that it's not really nice.

- You can put the mailcontent on your server. If the user is trusting/dumb enough to click, you can open a link (with an id) and get the info from the loaded webpage
- You can add images, is the user loads those (not default!) you get some information

etc. But for sending plain mail like this: no chance.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Daniel that it might not be legal to do so.

However, if I believe that your intentions are harmless, I'd suggest to use a hashed URL for an Image, unique per each e-mail sent. This URL points to a PHP file that matches it in a DB and marks the e-mail instance as delivered and read once the image is loaded.

Of course, the reader must have accepted to load the images from your e-mails. Otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, I don't think this is possible at all.

There is a "read receipt" system built into some email clients which can send automatic notification to the sender when an email is opened, but it's optional - the recipient may have disabled it, or may be using email software that doesn't support it.

But in any case, that doesn't include the user's IP address in the notification.

If you send HTML mails, you could include an embedded graphic in the message which would load from your server. But most email clients block external graphics for security reasons (ie precisely to avoid sharing their IP address and other details with an unknown sender).

You can't use Javascript because it also doesn't work in emails for security reasons.

Regardless, whatever you do will be entirely dependent on the capabilities of the recipient's email system and their settings. You have no control over that, and most user's settings will probably block whatever you try to do.

In short, you're not going to get what you want.

Simple answer: Just ask the users for the information you need, rather than trying to steal it from them. Maybe you should have town and country fields as part of the form that your users fill in to sign up to your mailing list.

Answer (score -1):

We can host tracking code in our c panel and generate one image link. Whenever image load into the email body it triggers the code and we can collect email id, ip address and time in csv file.

Comment: No, this doesn't work for most mail clients anymore.

Comment: I block the loading of images in Gmail and Outlook.  How do you track me?